# Grails I don't understand how to use async with data service

Tags: grails

Good Morning All,

I am importing a very large csv file.  So, I try to use the grails async plugin.

https://async.grails.org/latest/guide/index.html

I follow the example.  However, it is giving me a session not found error. I google it and they say I cannot use async for the data service because the data service is running from a different thread. (or something like that).  I don't understand the solution they suggested in the other posts.

What do I need to put in the p = task {} block to make it work?
Would you show me what to type in the block please?  Thanks!

I have a bookService.  The bookService has a importCsv(String csv) method that take the string read from a csv file. The BookController has an import action that will read the csv file and call the importCsv() method in the BookService to save the books to the database.

```
class BookController {
   def import {
      ...
      String csv = csvFile.text() // read the csv file
      def p = task {
         bookService.importCsv(csv)
      }
   }
}
```

```
abstract class BookService implements IBookService {
  ProcessCsvService processCsvService

  int importCsv(String csv) {
        csv.toCsvReader(['skipLines':1]).eachLine { cols ->
            def fields = processCsvService.process(cols) //process the rows and get the values
            def newBook = new Book(fields) // fill out the info and create a new book
            save(newBook)
        }
  }

} // book serivice class
```

Comment: Some of the info at https://async.grails.org/latest/guide/index.html#asyncGorm should be helpful.

Comment: I don't understand the example.  They have `def p = Person.async.getAll(1L, 2L, 3L)` but I have `p = task {}`.  I don't know where or what to type to apply the example to my BookController.